# Помогите улучшить архитектуру нейросети

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow

**Архитектура:**

```
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0.001,
                           patience=3, verbose=1, mode='auto')
chkpt = ModelCheckpoint('architecture.hdf5', 
                        monitor='val_loss', 
                        verbose=1, 
                        save_best_only=True, 
                        mode='auto')
callbacks = [early_stop, chkpt]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 32))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2)) 
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax"))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=50,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=1, callbacks=callbacks)
scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=128)
```

**Задача:**

Помогите улучшить архитектуру данной нейронной сети. Подскажите что убрать/добавить. 
**Ссылка на dataset для обучения:** https://yadi.sk/i/VMvEW4B2ACSB3A

**Ps:** `_label_1` это категория тендеров которая не подходит для скачивания

Comment: о каком дата сете идет речь в вопросе?

Comment: @MaxU сейчас добавлю

Comment: @MaxU добавил ссылку на dataset

Comment: Можете показать как вы обрабатываете текст? От этого может много зависеть...

Comment: Какую точность выдает данная архитектура после 20-ти и после 50-ти эпох обучения?

Comment: @MaxU после примерно 15ой эпохи начинается переобучение. Val_acc около 89% val_loss около 0,29.

Comment: @MaxU для обработки текста делаю токенизацию, и в таком виде подаю на вход нейросети.

Comment: Попробую на выходных поработать с этими данными. Если что-то получится - напишу ответ...

Comment: Сегодня днём напишу подробный вопрос со всеми деталями. Как сделаю, оставлю тут ссылку

Comment: @MaxU https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/939579/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%85%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9