# Не работает torch.nn.Conv2d

Tags: python, python-3.x, нейронные-сети, pytorch

Кусок кода модели:

```
embedding_length = 50
in_channels = 1
out_channels = 7
kernel_heights = [3, 5, 7]
stride = 1
padding = 2

self.word_embeddings = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_length)
self.word_embeddings.weight = nn.Parameter(weights, requires_grad=False)
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, (kernel_heights[0], embedding_length), stride, padding)
```

Во время выполнения прямого прохода, исполняется следующий код:

```
input = self.word_embeddings(input_sentences)
input = input.unsqueeze(1)
conv_out = self.conv1(input)
```

На строке с вычислением переменной `conv_out`, генерируется исключение:

> RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight
>   [7, 1, 3, 50], but got 3-dimensional input of size [3, 1, 50] instead

Почему должен передаваться на вход `conv1` тензор размера [7, 1, 3, 50]?

Comment: `Пальцем в небо`, мб это связанно с `out_channels = 7`?

Comment: @gil9red Ну, это капитанский ответ. Это я понимаю. Я не понимаю, почему я должен на вход подавать тензор, который зависит от выходного числа каналов.

Comment: По-моему здесь надо использовать `Conv1D` вместо `Conv2D`. [Вот пример на Keras](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/939707/211923)

Comment: @MaxU Почему Conv1D? Мне нужно свёртки делать для нескольких слов. Эмбединги -- это w2v, а точнее glove

Comment: @hedgehogues, потому что `Conv1D` ожидает на вход 3D тензор, а `Conv2D` - 4D тензор. Откуда будете брать четвертое измерение? ;-) Можно конечно превратить 3D в 4D, например `(K, L, M)` --> `(K,L,M,1)`, но зачем?

Comment: @MaxU Если я буду использовать 1D свёртку, то я не смогу получить свёртку для нескольких слов. Т.е. при помощи 1D я получу лишь только conv1d(w_i). При помощи 2D -- conv2d(w_{i-1}, w_{i}, w_{i+1}).

Comment: @MaxU я поступил, как Вы предложили. `(K, L, M) --> (K,L,M,1)`. Долго ковырялся с тем, как это сделать. Порешал вот так `torch.tensor([[t]], dtype=torch.long)`

Comment: я не уверен что это даст то, что вы хотите сделать... Можно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48999713/5741205) попробовать, но сам я с этим не разбирался... Напишите пожалуйста если что-нибудь получится

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89768/discussion-between-hedgehogues-and-maxu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короткий ответ выглядит так:

```
input_sentences = torch.tensor([[t]], dtype=torch.long)
input = self.word_embeddings(input_sentences)
conv_out = self.conv1(input)
```

Чуть более длинный ответ заключается в том, что во многих фреймворках, которые реализуют нейронные сети, используются в таком случае 4х мерные тензоры. Поясню. 2 измерения на изображение (или эмбеддинг), ещё 1 измерение на channels (цвета), ещё одно измерение для того, чтобы передавать в NN, сразу несколько изображений (batch). Вот и здесь получается, что есть `t` -- тензор, который, вообще говоря 2х мерный (в данном случае, это эмбеддинги -- последовательность векторизованных слов). Других же измерений нет. Поэтому их приходится добавлять руками так, как это сделано выше.

Следует отметить, что внутри NN каналы могут использоваться как дополнительные фильтры при распространении сигнала по нейронной сети.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке выше изображено следующее:

Входные цветные изображение (RGB скорее всего, т.е. 224x224x3, т.е. 224х224xRGB). Далее RGB свернули при помощи Conv3D аж 64 раза и получили 64 различных фильтра. Их можно воспринимать, как различные способы трактования информации. И т.д. При этом, на рисунке не указано ещё одно измерение, которое должно обозначать число изображений, для которых будет считаться loss в данном батче.

Для чего мне нужна была такого рода конструкция. Я работаю с текстами и мне нужны свёртки для сворачивания векторов. В частности, вот [так](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.5882.pdf):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Приведу подробную реализацию модели:

```
from torch.functional import F
import torch.nn as nn


class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dense, channels, kernels, paddings, keep_probab,
                 vocab_size, embedding_length, weights):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()

        self.dense = dense
        self.channels = channels
        self.kernels = kernels
        self.paddings = paddings
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size
        self.embedding_length = embedding_length

        self.word_embeddings = self.__create_embedding(weights)
        self.conv1 = self.__create_convolution(0)
        self.conv2 = self.__create_convolution(1)
        self.conv3 = self.__create_convolution(2)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(keep_probab)
        self.result = self.__create_dense()

    def __create_dense(self):
        return nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.dense[0], self.dense[1]),
            nn.ReLU(),

            nn.Linear(self.dense[1], self.dense[2]),
            nn.ReLU(),

            nn.Linear(self.dense[2], self.dense[3]),
            nn.ReLU(),

            nn.Linear(self.dense[3], self.dense[4]),
            nn.ReLU(),

            nn.Softmax()
        )

    def __create_embedding(self, weights):
        word_embeddings = nn.Embedding(self.vocab_size, self.embedding_length)
        word_embeddings.weight = nn.Parameter(weights, requires_grad=False)
        return word_embeddings

    def __create_convolution(self, step):
        return nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(
                in_channels=self.channels[step],
                out_channels=self.channels[step+1],
                kernel_size=(self.kernels[step], self.embedding_length if step == 0 else 1),
                padding=(self.paddings[step], 0),
            ),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(self.kernels[step], 1), padding=(1, 0), stride=(1, 1)),
        )

    def forward(self, x):

        x = self.word_embeddings(x)
        max_out1 = self.conv1(x)
        max_out2 = self.conv2(max_out1)
        max_out3 = self.conv3(max_out2)

        # all_out = torch.cat((max_out1, max_out2, max_out3), 0)
        dropout = self.dropout(max_out3)
        logits = self.result(dropout.flatten())

        return logits
```

В данном случае, в качестве примера обучающей выборки следует передавать тензор вида:

```
torch.tensor([[t]], dtype=torch.long)
```

В заключение, я приведу пример ещё одной нейронки, которую я взял из официальной доки [pyTorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-cifar10-tutorial-py). Простой классификатор на 10 классов. Объявим нейронку:

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))  # Свёртка с пулингом
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))  # Свёртка с пулингом
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)  # Преобразование к вектору 1x400
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))  # Dense
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))  # Dense
        x = self.fc3(x)  # Dense
        return x
```

Зададим нейронку, критерий и оптимизатор.

```
import torch.optim as optim

net = Net()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
```

Получаем данные. Вот здесь я обращаю Ваше внимание на `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`. В параметре `batch_size=4` задаётся число примеров, которые будут передаваться в NN или измерение A (AxBxCxD), где B -- число каналов, CXD -- размер изображения или число_словХэмбеддинг.

```
transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False,
                                       download=True, transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=4,
                                         shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

classes = ('plane', 'car', 'bird', 'cat',
           'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck')
```

Одно из обсуждений приведено [тут](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-do-convolution-on-tube-tensors-3d-conv/21446)