# Как улучшить архитектуру нейронной сети?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow

**Вопрос:**

Нейронная сеть выдёт плохие результаты при обчении, т.к особого опыта в сфере не имею, не могу понять в чём проблема. В чём собственно говоря может быть проблема? В самом датасете? В плохой архитектуре?

**Подготовка датасета:**

```
def clear_str(line):
    reg = re.compile('[^а-яА-Я ]')
    stemmer = SnowballStemmer("russian") 
    reg.sub('', line)
    clean_step_1 = reg.sub('', line).lower()

    clean_step_2 = ""
    for word in clean_step_1.split(" "):
        if len(word) > 3:
            clean_step_2 += word+" "
    clean_step_3 = ""
    for word in clean_step_2.split(" "):
        clean_step_3 += str(stemmer.stem(word))+" "
    if len(clean_step_3.split(" ")) > 1:
        return clean_step_3
    elif len(clean_step_3.split(" ")) <= 1:
        return "Nan"

df = pd.read_csv("data.txt", sep='<sep_char>',encoding = "utf-8", engine='python', names=["description", "label"]).astype(str)
df['description'] = df.description.apply(clear_str)
df.drop(df.index[df['label'] == "None"], inplace = True)
df.drop(df.index[df['description'] == "Nan"], inplace = True)

X_raw = df['description'].values
Y_raw = df['label'].values

num_classes = len(df.drop_duplicates(subset='label', keep='first', inplace=False))
max_words = 1000

tokenizer = keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(max_words)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_raw)
x_data = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(X_raw)

encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y_raw)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y_raw)
y_data = keras.utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y, num_classes)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_data, y_data, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

**Архитектура нейронной сети:**

```
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0.001,patience=3, verbose=1, mode='auto')
chkpt = ModelCheckpoint('architecture.hdf5', monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='auto')
callbacks = [early_stop, chkpt]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(max_words,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=256, epochs=30, verbose=1, callbacks=callbacks, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

**Полный код:**

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer 
import keras
from sklearn import preprocessing
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import load_model

def clear_str(line):
    reg = re.compile('[^а-яА-Я ]')
    stemmer = SnowballStemmer("russian") 
    reg.sub('', line)
    clean_step_1 = reg.sub('', line).lower()

    clean_step_2 = ""
    for word in clean_step_1.split(" "):
        if len(word) > 3:
            clean_step_2 += word+" "
    clean_step_3 = ""
    for word in clean_step_2.split(" "):
        clean_step_3 += str(stemmer.stem(word))+" "
    if len(clean_step_3.split(" ")) > 1:
        return clean_step_3
    elif len(clean_step_3.split(" ")) <= 1:
        return "Nan"

df = pd.read_csv("data.txt", sep='<sep_char>',encoding = "utf-8", engine='python', names=["description", "label"]).astype(str)
df['description'] = df.description.apply(clear_str)
df.drop(df.index[df['label'] == "None"], inplace = True)
df.drop(df.index[df['description'] == "Nan"], inplace = True)

X_raw = df['description'].values
Y_raw = df['label'].values

num_classes = len(df.drop_duplicates(subset='label', keep='first', inplace=False))
max_words = 1000

tokenizer = keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(max_words)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_raw)
x_data = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(X_raw)

encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y_raw)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y_raw)
y_data = keras.utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y, num_classes)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_data, y_data, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0.001,patience=3, verbose=1, mode='auto')
chkpt = ModelCheckpoint('architecture.hdf5', monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='auto')
callbacks = [early_stop, chkpt]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(max_words,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=256, epochs=30, verbose=1, callbacks=callbacks, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

**Данные по текущей версиии архитектуры:**

loss: 0.7271 acc: 0.7638 val_loss: 0.9435 val_acc: 0.7177

**ссылка на датасет:** https://yadi.sk/d/n1iuqlOssGFo9A

Comment: плохие результаты - это какие? Вы пробовали решения из [другого вашего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/939579/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%85%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8)? какие результаты дают они?

Comment: @MaxU 1. на реальных, не тренировочных данных нейросеть не справляется со своей задачей. 2. да, я пробовал вариант с embendig, и получил более плохой результат, вариант с матрицей как в этом случае, подходит лучше, но его очевидно нужно доработать. Пробовал добавлять слоёв, игрался со значением dropout, уменьшал/увеличивал кол-во нейроннов, но это дало результат в районе пары сотых процента.

Comment: Какая точность на обучающей выборке? Какая на тестовой? Какую точность показывает [это решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/939738/211923)?

Comment: сейчас добавлю в вопрос

Comment: @MaxU добавил исправления